# How do i start a watch kit notification?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Im creating a app and i would like know how to start a notification to apple watch from apple watch and from iphone to apple watch

I thought local and remote notification could anyone help me????

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean notifications to test your app? Or notifications in general? For notifications in general, I think (but I'm not 100% sure tough) that right now you can't choose where a notification appears, and that both local and remote notifications received by the containing iPhone app will be displayed by Apple Watch (and you can customise their behaviour and style).
To test notifications on Apple Watch, edit the scheme of your watch app and choose to display a notification from a .apns file.

Answer (score 0):

Notification (local or remote) will be appeared on your Apple Watch device as it is paired with your iPhone, iPhone is locked and watches are on your wrist.

To handle incoming notifications on your WatchKit App you should create a Notification Interface Controller in your WatchKit App target's storyboard.

First it will be as a static interface. Also you can add the dynamic one and create a subclass of `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` in WatchKit Extension. Link this subclass with the storyboard dynamic notification controller in Identity Inspector pane.

After all you should implement next methods in your subclass:

```
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:withCompletion:
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion:
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

in completion with **x401om** awnser :

you can't fire a local notification from apple watch to iPhone. in fact you can't choose to :

**Senario 1** : The user have the phone non-locked, the notification (local or push) is always delivered to the iphone, and not the watch

**Senario 2** : The iphone is locked and watch is on you're watch, and you have done some local or push notification (for local at an date and time) then the apple watch recieve the notification.